# Are there any open source scheduling tools for AWS Redshift?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift, talend, amazon-data-pipeline

I have few sql statements (insert, update, delete, truncate) to be executed in a transaction, every 5 mins. I cannot use AWS Data Pipeline since minimum scheduling interval is 15 mins for pipeline. Are there any open source tools I can use? Can I use talend open studio to achieve this?

Comment: Via a cron job and a SQL file?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to overcome the limitation of the 15 min schedule interval by creating 3 pipelines and starting them 5 min apart.

Another solution would be to use OnDemand pipeline. Then you can create a CloudWatch event (with schedule) to trigger lambda function. Inside the lambda you can start the pipeline execution.

Comment: I am not sure if it is possible to perform insert, update, delete, truncate on redshift tables with pipeline, is it?\